# Optimized javascript code to find 3 largest element and its indexes in array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I need a more optimized version of this javascript code to find the 3 largest values in an array. I need to get the indexes of the largest numbers. Are there any other easier methods to solve the problem?

```js
var maxIndex = new Array();
var maxPoints = new Array();
var scoreByPattern = new Array(93, 17, 56, 91, 98, 33, 9, 38, 55, 78, 29, 81, 60);

function findLargest3() {
  maxPoints[0] = 0;
  maxPoints[1] = 0;
  maxPoints[2] = 0; 
  
  for (i = 0; i < scoreByPattern.length; i++) {
    if (scoreByPattern[i] > maxPoints[0]) {
      maxPoints[0] = scoreByPattern[i];
      maxIndex[0] = i;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < scoreByPattern.length; i++) {
    if (scoreByPattern[i] > maxPoints[1] && scoreByPattern[i] < maxPoints[0]) {
      maxPoints[1] = scoreByPattern[i];
      maxIndex[1] = i;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < scoreByPattern.length; i++) {
    if (scoreByPattern[i] > maxPoints[2] && scoreByPattern[i] < maxPoints[1]) {
      maxPoints[2] = scoreByPattern[i];
      maxIndex[2] = i;
    }
  }

  console.log(scoreByPattern + "/******/" + maxPoints[0] + "/" + maxPoints[1] + "/" + maxPoints[2]);
  //alert(maxIndex);
}

findLargest3();
```

Comment: sort and get three last elements of array

Comment: On the topic of JavaScript optimization: Google I/O 2012 - Breaking the JavaScript Speed Limit: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJPdhx5zTaw

Comment: The answer is simple for loop that updates the best 1,2 and 3.

Comment: Hey Tilak, what's up now? Did you sove your Problem. Mind if you accept one of the answers?

Comment: random unaccept 6 months later...?! Both my answer and your new accepted answer simply sort the array...

Comment: For anyone looking for N highest lowest number, referrer to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21690101/1090562)

Comment: Note that the code presented determines *three largest **distinct** values* (and indexes thereof), which in case of duplicates among the three largest values will *not* be the same as *three largest elements*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can sort the array descending. Then the indexes of the highest 3 values will be the first three items in the array. You can access them individually or use `slice()` to get them at once. The example below shows both methods.

```js
var maxPoints = new Array();
var scoreByPattern = new Array(93, 17, 56, 91, 98, 33, 9, 38, 55, 78, 29, 81, 60);

findLargest3();

function findLargest3() {
  scoreByPattern.sort((a, b) => a < b ? 1 : a > b ? -1 : 0);
  
  console.log(scoreByPattern + "/******/" + scoreByPattern[0] + "/" + scoreByPattern[1] + "/" + scoreByPattern[2]);  
  console.log(scoreByPattern.slice(0, 3));
}
```

Comment: I think sorting is bad here, you can do it in O(n).

Comment: I guess that, if you sort by using a sort function, it will be slower then doing a normal built-in `sort()` followed by `reverse()`. If you specify a sorting function, you can as well do a `forEach` and just take the highest 3 values out.

Comment: You could indeed. Most ways of skinning this particular cat had already been put into this answer before I posted this method. Personally, I'd use yours @WouterH.

Comment: Considering the fact, that sorting the huge array might be very costly I'd prefer not to sort it first. Have a look at my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11792417/1047823).

Comment: I feel like this didn't really answer the question; I don't know why it is upvoted so much. This returns indexes `[0,1,2]` and not `[4,0,3]` as in the OP's provided solution. This also has the side-effect of "sorting" the original array, which the OP's posted solution did not. To make this solution work, you'd have to copy the original array, sort the copy to take the first 3 values, & use something like `indexOf` on the original array to get the indexes back out. At that point, I think the performance may be worse than the original solution.

Comment: @Lovethenakedgun Just to clarify on this very old answer, the OP added the 'and its indexes' requirement  *after*  I had posted this solution. I still don't know why it's accepted though, given it didn't answer that point.

Answer (score 13):

**Modified version**

I have modified my answer to make it more generic. It searches for the indices of the n largest numbers of elements in the array:

```
var scoreByPattern = [93,255,17,56,91,98,33,9,38,55,78,29,81,60];

function findIndicesOfMax(inp, count) {
    var outp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
        outp.push(i); // add index to output array
        if (outp.length > count) {
            outp.sort(function(a, b) { return inp[b] - inp[a]; }); // descending sort the output array
            outp.pop(); // remove the last index (index of smallest element in output array)
        }
    }
    return outp;
}

// show original array
console.log(scoreByPattern);

// get indices of 3 greatest elements
var indices = findIndicesOfMax(scoreByPattern, 3);
console.log(indices);

// show 3 greatest scores
for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++)
    console.log(scoreByPattern[indices[i]]);
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQtvG/)

Comment: Good answer; concise & output matches OP's. However, I don't see a reason to call `sort` for each loop. Loop is `O(N)` but sort is `O(N Log(N))`. I think sorting once & slicing "count" would be a performance improvement in general. I.e. `for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) { outp.push(i); } outp.sort(function(a, b) { return inp[b] - inp[a]; }); return outp.slice(0, count);` On my machine, Win10 Firefox, I measured about a ~20% improvement & same output.

Comment: Additionally; _this is significantly slower than the original answer_, by about 30x. If you're going to sort, like most of the answers suggest (imo inappropriately) then you have to clone the array to avoid the side-effect of sorting, as you have. If in getting the "top N" indexes though, N < Log2(array.length); then _not_ sorting is actually preferable computationally.

Comment: The question was not about performance but about "an easier methods to solve the problem", which is very subjective and more something for codereview instead of stackoverflow. However, this question is 8 years old, so maybe not worth moving it.

Comment: Btw, the sort only happens on the output array, which doesn't affect the input and can at max contain 3 elements. Sorting an array with 3 elements won't slow you down that much. There are more performant ways to deal with that, but that was not the question.

Comment: Yours is one of the better "answers" here, as it actually outputs what the OP asked. But because it actually answered the question, I just wanted to point out that this solution is much slower. "I need a more optimized version of this javascript code" is admittedly vague, but providing a solution with a much higher time complexity isn't ideal without noting it. Also `sort` is called `scoreByPattern - 3` times, so even though it only has "3 elements", for an input array of any practical size, it's a lot of wasted execution.

Comment: I agree that the side-effect of sorting in a loop should have been mentioned somehow. You've retriggered my interest to create a more performant solution for this question. Challenge accepted, I'll try to beat your answer in my spare time :D

Answer (score 8):

Without sorting the huge array: Runs in `O(n)` which is superior to anything that involves sorting the original array. Returns an array of the largest values and their indices in the initial array. With some smarter code you can eliminate the sorting of the small array which results in a better worst-case performance.

```js
var ar = [93, 17, 56, 91, 98, 33, 9, 38, 55, 78, 29, 81, 60];
console.log(`input is: ${ar}`);

function getMax(ar){
    if (ar.length <= 3) return ar;
    let max = [{value:ar[0],index:0},
               {value:ar[1],index:1},
               {value:ar[2],index:2}];
    max.sort((a,b)=>a.value-b.value);
        
    for (let i = 3;i<ar.length;i++){
        if (ar[i] > max[0].value){
           max[0] = {value:ar[i],index:i};
           max.sort((a,b)=>a.value-b.value);
        }
    }
    return max;
}

result = getMax(ar);

console.log('the three largest values are:');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @greybeard what exactly do you mean? Also, nice necro;-)

Comment: (`nice necro` blame goes to [heinels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65528315/3789665)) `what exactly do you mean` not sure, actually: probably missed "the pre-loop sort of `max`". (My new peeve would be returning an array of {value, index} pairs for 3 < length and an array of values otherwise.)

Answer (score 4):

The default javascript sort callback won't work well because it sorts in a [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). 10 would become before 5(because of the 1)

No credit to me but:

```
my_array.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a-b;
});
```

Comment: I need indexes of the largest elements . so cant sort the array .

Comment: @SaniHuttunen `[4,5,26,2,6,256].sort()
//[2, 256, 26, 4, 5, 6];` Not expected imo..

Comment: @tilak if you need to preserve indexes, I think you should update your question whit this relevant detail

Comment: @Esailija, thanks for good looking edit. For the ones interested. Just type the comment code from Esailija in a browser console.(at least chrome shows the `wrong` order)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use a combination of [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

This simple one liner will solve your problem.

```
[1, -5, 2, 8, 17, 0, -2].sort(function(a, b){return b - a}).slice(0, 3)
```

So if you have an array and want to find N biggest values:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){return b - a}).slice(0, n)
```

And for N smallest values:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){return a - b}).slice(0, n)
```

Comment: `This simple one liner` won't satisfy `I need indexes of largest numbers`.

Comment: This also has the side-effect of "sorting" the original array. If the order of the original indexes matters, this won't work without first cloning the array & then doing a reverse lookup of the original indexes via the highest / lowest values. Doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: this solution was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks @salvadordali

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a fairly normal distribution, this should be fairly optimal:

```
var max_three, numbers = new Array(93,17,56,91,98,33,9,38,55,78,29,81,60);

max_three = (function (numbers) {
    var i, one, two, three;
    one = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    two = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    three = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {
        num = numbers[i];
        if (num > three) {
            if (num >= two) {
                three = two;
                if (num >= one) {
                    two = one;
                    one = num;
                }
                else {
                    two = num;
                }
            }
            else {
                three = num;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return [one, two, three]

}(numbers))

document.write(max_three)​​​​​​​
```

```
98, 93, 91
```

Comment: If all the elements of the array are number that little than -9999, this algorithm won't work

Comment: @barak: Just initialize `one, two, three` with the first value from `numbers`

Comment: @barak1412 that's correct although easy to fix. There is also no specification of what to do when the array.length is less than 3

Comment: Doesn't look bad for returning the largest values - the question was updated to `I need indexes of largest numbers` while you answered.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an **optimized solution** for your problem without using sort or other complex array method :

```js
var maxIndex = new Array();
var maxPoints = new Array();
var scoreByPattern = new Array(93,17,56,91,98,33,9,38,55,78,29,81,60);
function findTop3(n) {
 for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i ++) {
  if (i === 0) {
   maxPoints.push(n[i]);
   maxIndex.push(i);
  } else if (i === 1) {
   if (n[i] > maxPoints[0]) {
    maxPoints.push(maxPoints[0]);    
    maxPoints[0] = n[i];
    maxIndex.push(maxIndex[0]);
    maxIndex[0] = i;
   } else {
    maxPoints.push(n[i]);
    maxIndex.push(i);
   }
  } else if (i === 2) {
   if (n[i] > maxPoints[0]) {
    maxPoints.push(maxPoints[0]);
    maxPoints[1] = maxPoints[0];
    maxPoints[0] = n[i];
    maxIndex.push(maxIndex[0]);
    maxIndex[1] = maxIndex[0];
    maxIndex[0] = i;
    
   } else {
    if (n[i] > maxPoints[1]) {
     maxPoints.push(maxPoints[1]);
     maxPoints[1] = n[i];
     maxIndex.push(maxIndex[1]);
     maxIndex[1] = i;
    } else {
     maxPoints.push(n[i]);
     maxIndex.push(i);
    }
   }
  } else {
   if (n[i] > maxPoints[0]) {
    maxPoints[2] = maxPoints[1];
    maxPoints[1] = maxPoints[0];
    maxPoints[0] = n[i];
    maxIndex[2] = maxIndex[1];
    maxIndex[1] = maxIndex[0];
    maxIndex[0] = i;
   } else {
    if (n[i] > maxPoints[1]) {
     maxPoints[2] = maxPoints[1];
     maxPoints[1] = n[i];
     maxIndex[2] = maxIndex[1];
     maxIndex[1] = i;
    } else if(n[i] > maxPoints[2]) {
     maxPoints[2] = n[i];
     maxIndex[2] = i;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
findTop3(scoreByPattern);
console.log('Top Elements: ', maxPoints);
console.log('With Index: ', maxIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: Everything below is still valid. However, it was clarified to me in a comment that the original question did not ask for indexes, and many of the answers were responding to the preexisting question. Apologies for any curtness in my original post.

Even looking at the original question however, I still disagree with recommending sorting in general for this type of question.

---

I can't believe how many of these answers are worse than the OP's provided solution. Most are more concise, but either:

- Don't answer the question. Often only providing the top 3 values, when the question also asks for the *indexes* of the top 3 values.
- Suggest "sorting" but without even mentioning performance, side-effects or Big-O notation.

This may be a little too long for SO, but I feel like this is pertinent information.

---

> 1. I need a more optimized version of this javascript code to find the 3 largest values in an array.
> 2. I need to get the indexes of the largest numbers.
> 3. Are there any other easier methods to solve the problem?

I take (3) to mean "I want the method to be more concise / readable", (2) as "indices to be available in the output directly", and (1) to mean "I want the code to be as efficient as possible".

Starting from (3) as it'd be most useful to people: Your original algorithm is quite efficient, but you're basically duplicating code in each of the 3 loops; the only difference in each loop really is that the index changes. If you just wanted to cut down on the number of characters, you could re-write your algorithm (with a couple minor caveats<sup>1</sup>) as:

```
function findLargest3(arry) {
  const max = {
    indices: new Array(0, 0, 0),
    points : new Array(0, 0, 0)
  }
  
  // Inner private function to remove duplicate code
  // Modifies "max" as a side-effect
  function setLargest (idx) {
    const lastMax = max.points[idx - 1] || Number.MAX_VALUE;
    for (let i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {
      if (arry[i] > max.points[idx] && arry[i] < lastMax) {
        max.points[idx] = arry[i];
        max.indices[idx] = i;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Get's the 0'th, 1st, and 2nd largest items
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setLargest(i);
  }
  
  return max;
}

let scoreByPattern = new Array(93, 17, 56, 91, 98, 33, 9, 38, 55, 78, 29, 81, 60);
let max = findLargest3(scoreByPattern);
console.log(scoreByPattern + "/******/" + max.points.join("/"));
```

Beyond the addition of the function, the only thing I really had to add was: `const lastMax = max.points[idx - 1] || Number.MAX_VALUE;`. This was just for the case where `idx == 0`. As there is no `max.points[-1]`. We want that second check to always return true, so if `max.points[idx - 1]` doesn't exist, set it to the highest possible value via `||`.

This actually ends up being about 4 times slower than your implementation. That slowness is a result of *not* directly modifying global state (which is faster but harder to maintain) & including that inner function rather than the code duplication. Replacing the inner function with your original duplicated code & leaving every other change the same ends up being 40% faster to execute, because it avoids the creation & calling of the function entirely; but again is easier to read. It also makes extending `findLargest3` to become `findLargest5` or `findLargestN` much simpler.

Additionally, it should be the same Big-O as your original solution (see my answer to 1), unlike the solutions involving `sort`; which means it will scale as well as your original solution, while being easier to read & maintain. If you *really* need the performance, there's very little wrong with your original solution, and I'd even argue your original solution's better than some of the posted solutions. (For example, from rough testing, increasing the size of the array to ~100 elements makes my solution run about ~3x slower, but makes a solution using `sort` run more than 6x slower).

---

<sup>1</sup>Note: There is one major issue with your algorithm, and that's that `i` is "globally scoped". If you wrote the following, it would run for `i==0` and then loop forever with `i==scoreByPattern.length` & would never finish:

```
// Outer loop
for (var i = 0; i <= scoreByPattern.length + 1; i++) {
    findLargest3()
}
```

That's because your `for (i = 0 ...` statements don't reference a "local" version of `i` & will fall back to one that's been defined in a previous scope (or global if it doesn't find one). Your loops always leave `i` set to `scoreByPattern.length` when they finish, which would change the value in this outer loop. Certain languages & language constructs (`foreach` in C# for example) actually won't compile if you've attempted to modify an iterator during a loop. The fix is actually *really* simple, & it's just to say `var i` or `let i` in your loop declaration & then `i` will only refer to a variable local to the function.

There's also the minor problem of your original algorithm ignoring duplicates in the array. If I add another `93` to the end of your original array, it still returns the top values as `[98, 93, 91]`. I didn't change this in my solution, as it may be intentional (e.g. the top three "values" are 98, 93, and 91, but 93 just happens to occur twice). To fix, rather than checking that `arry[i] < max.points[...` you would just check that `i` isn't already in `max.indices`. Depending on the number of duplicates, this could slow the algorithm down (without a rewrite) but assuming `duplicates << array.length` then it wouldn't be noticeably slower.

And while not being a "problem" per-se, it's generally not ideal to have "global state" (i.e. `scoreByPattern, maxPoints, maxIndex`) & then have them be mutated by a function. It can be computationally faster, but harder to maintain. That's why I moved the declaration of `maxPoints / maxIndex` into the function body & made it request `scoreByPattern` as a parameter. There are plenty of scenarios where that'd be fine (e.g. Object member variables & mutator methods). But here, `findLargest3` really seems like a helper function / functional in nature, & thus ideally shouldn't have side-effects (i.e. modify external state / the parameters that are passed to it).

---

Briefly mentioning (2): If the indexes themselves matter, sorting the array doesn't really make sense except in some very particular circumstances (see my answer to point 1). Sorting is an "in-place" operation using Javascript's `sort` method on the array directly. This means it will modify the original array in most of these answers; so the original indexes are actually lost & also has other consequences for the rest of the program. In order to use sort to get the top N values, you'd have to copy the array first, sort the copy, take the top 3 values, then iterate through the original array ~3 times trying to match using `indexOf` or similar (and dealing with duplicates).

This is obviously a waste of resources, as some of these answers are as much as 30 times slower than the original. You could try and generate a list of "indexes" rather than values, sort them based on the original array, & that'd be slightly faster. But in this specific case where we only want "the top 3" (again, see my answer to point 1) unless I'm crazy, *sorting will almost always be slower*.

---

Finally, looking at (1) it's useful to apply a concept called "Big-O notation" when analysing algorithms. I'd suggest googling it & having a read, but broad-strokes: we want to see how efficient an algorithm is, as the length of the input increases. E.g. In your application, we've got the array `scoreByPattern` which we'll say has a length of `N`, as well as an explicit "3 indexes / values" imposed by your question, but it's useful to be able to say "return the top `M` indexes / values". If `scoreByPattern` or `top M` are very short, then the complexity of the algorithm won't really matter, but if they've got 100's to 100's of thousands of elements, then their computational complexity becomes really significant.

Also, it's important to say that with an array in JS, if you know the index, a "lookup" is actually a nearly instantaneous operation `~Big O(1)`. Also, in Big-O, we tend to only look at the "dominant" term of an analysis & ignore any constant-time factors. E.g. If a solution is `10x O(1) + 2x O(N)` (10 constant time operations + 2 operations for each item in a list of length `N`) we say the Big-O of the solution is `O(N)`. This is because, for a reasonably long list, if we doubled the value of N, the time taken will roughly double. If it was bounded by an O(N<sup>2</sup>) operation & the list length was doubled, it would take 2<sup>2</sup> times longer (i.e. 4 times slower).

So your original solution is:

- Some constant time steps
- Iterate through the list once, do two boolean checks & two assignments
- Do this again
- Do this a third time

Meaning it'd be something like `kO(1) + 3*cO(N)` where `k` & `c` are some constants, leaving it as: `O(N)` in general. If we wanted the "Top `M` indexes" you'd end up with: `MO(N)` which ends up being `O(NM)` (i.e. Big-O of `N * M`). Why is this important?

`sort` is Big-O of `O(N Log2(N))` what this means is that for say, a list of ~64 items, sort will take roughly `64 * Log2(64) == 64 * 6 == ~384ish operations`. So comparing your solution to ones involving `sort`, unless `M > Log2(N)`, not sorting is preferable.

To put that into perspective: if your list has 100 items, you'd need to be trying to get more than 6 "largest" items for sorting to be more efficient. If it was 100,000 items, you'd need to be trying to get more than 16 "largest" items. In this use-case, especially since you've explicitly said "3", it almost always makes more sense *not* to sort. Particularly, because you're trying to get indices; if you *only* wanted values, then the sorting solutions may be preferable just because they're simple.

You could probably tune your algorithm a bit more to speed it up further, but from rough testing: I think your solution is *already* the fastest solution here. If you want to make it easier to maintain / read / extend, that's definitely possible; but that really shouldn't come at the expense of actually increasing "time complexity" (i.e. making the solution worse than `O(N)`) unless it *vastly* simplifies the implementation.

Comment: Looking back at this, since the top `M` values are sequential, you could replace `function setLargest(idx)` with `for (var idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++) { ... }` & it would work the same & probably be a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just sort it and take the first (or last if sorted in ascending order) three elements.

```
var maxPoints = new Array();
var scoreByPattern = new Array(93,17,56,91,98,33,9,38,55,78,29,81,60);
scoreByPattern.sort();
maxPoints[0] = scoreByPattern[scoreByPattern.length - 1];
maxPoints[1] = scoreByPattern[scoreByPattern.length - 2];
maxPoints[2] = scoreByPattern[scoreByPattern.length - 3];
```

**Edit**
If you need the indeces of the largest arrays you can make a copy which you sort and then find the indices in the original array:

```
var scoreByPattern = new Array(93,17,56,91,98,33,9,38,55,78,29,81,60);

// Make a copy of the original array.
var maxPoints = scoreByPattern.slice();

// Sort in descending order.
maxPoints.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a < b) { return 1; }
    else if (a == b) { return 0; }
    else { return -1; }

});

// Find the indices of the three largest elements in the original array.
var maxPointsIndices = new Array();
maxPointsIndices[0] = scoreByPattern.indexOf(maxPoints[0]);
maxPointsIndices[1] = scoreByPattern.indexOf(maxPoints[1]);
maxPointsIndices[2] = scoreByPattern.indexOf(maxPoints[2]);
```

Another approach to find the indices without sorting is this:

```
var scoreByPattern = new Array(93,17,56,91,98,33,9,38,55,78,29,81,60);
var maxIndices = new Array(Number.MIN_VALUE, Number.MIN_VALUE, Number.MIN_VALUE);

for (var i = 0; i < scoreByPattern.length; i++) {
  if (maxIndices[0] < scoreByPattern[i]) {
    maxIndices[2] = maxIndices[1];
    maxIndices[1] = maxIndices[0];
    maxIndices[0] = scoreByPattern[i];
  }
  else if (maxIndices[1] < scoreByPattern[i]) {
    maxIndices[2] = maxIndices[1];
    maxIndices[1] = scoreByPattern[i];
  }
  else if (maxIndices[2] < scoreByPattern[i]) maxIndices[2] = scoreByPattern[i];
}
```

Comment: The first approach will have a problem with a duplicate in the three largest values. The second one just gathers largest values instead of their indices, suggestive naming notwithstanding (compare `scoreByPattern[maxIndices[m]] < scoreByPattern[i]` and set `maxIndices[m] = i`).

Comment: Since uniqueness is not a requirement in OP the first approach is correct. The second approach is also correct since it gets the indices and not the values.

Comment: For the problem with duplicate, look at the result for (0, 9, 8, 7, 8).

Comment: Your second approach yields [ 98, 93, 91 ] and [ 9, 8, 8 ], respectively - values or indices?

Comment: Second approach yields `[4, 0, 3]`. I don't know where you're getting `[9, 8, 8]` from. And as for duplicates that was never a requirement.

Comment: Copy&paste into Firefox web console, add a `console.log(maxIndices)`, execute: `Array(3) [ 98, 93, 91 ]` - how, starting with above code, do you get `[4, 0, 3]`?

Comment: You probably meant the third approach. Well just do a reduce to get the indices of the three largest numbers: `maxIndices = maxIndices.reduce(function(a, e) {
    a.push(scoreByPattern.indexOf(e));
    return a;
}, []);`

Comment: You correctly assume that I meant the last approach: I don't count the one before the Edit:. Rather than another reduce, I'd change as in my first comment…

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/GGkSt/

```
var maxPoints = [];
var scoreByPattern = [93,17,56,91,98,33,9,38,55,78,29,81,60];

function cloneArray(array) {
    return array.map(function(i){ return i; });
}    
function max3(array) {
    return cloneArray(array).sort(function(a,b) { return b-a; }).slice(0,3);
}
function min3(array) {
     return cloneArray(array).sort(function(a,b) { return a-b; }).slice(0,3);
}

var array=scoreByPattern;
alert("Max:"+ max3(array)[0] +' '+max3(array)[1] +' '+max3(array)[2]);
alert("Min:"+ min3(array)[0] +' '+min3(array)[1] +' '+min3(array)[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get3TopItems(arr) {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function return a array whose element is a fixed two-element array with 1st element as the index and second as its value.

```js
function findTopValues(dataArray, n) {
  var resultArray = [];

  var dataArrayCopy = dataArray.slice();

  var topNArray = dataArrayCopy
    .sort(function (begin, end) {
      return end - begin;
    })
    .slice(0, n);
  for (let ele of topNArray) {
    resultArray.push([dataArray.indexOf(ele), ele]);
  }
  return resultArray;
}

var dataArray = [12,5,20,4,50,23,98,8];

console.log(findTopValues(dataArray,3))
```

Comment: This approach will have a problem with a duplicate in the three largest values.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that return `N` indexes of the `N` largest elements (in the case of equal values, it return the first indexes found).
In code, `N` is `qtyMax`.
Function has cost `O(n)`, in the worst case `n * qtyMax`.

```js
function maxIdxs(arr, qtyMax) {
    var maxIndex = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var m=0;
        while(m<qtyMax && arr[i]<=arr[maxIndex[m]])
            m++;
        if(m<qtyMax)
            maxIndex.splice(m, 0, i);
    }
    return maxIndex.slice(0, qtyMax);
}

console.log(maxIdxs( [1,23,46,35,20] , 0 )); // []
console.log(maxIdxs( []              , 3 )); // []
console.log(maxIdxs( [1,23]          , 3 )); // [1,0]
console.log(maxIdxs( [1,23,46,35,20] , 3 )); // [2,3,1]
console.log(maxIdxs( [1,40,40,40,40] , 3 )); // [1,2,3]
```

To obtain the corresponding function `minIdxs` (find `N` indexes of the smallest) you just need to replace `<=` with `>=` in the condition of the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without sorting:

```
let getLargest = (a,n)=>{
    let max,p,b=[],n1;
    for(let i=0;i<n;i++){
        max=a[0]
        p=false
        n1=0
        for(let j in a){
            if(max<a[j]){
                max=a[j]
                p=true
                n1=j
            }
        }
        if(!!p){
            b.push(max)
            a.splice(n1,1);
        }
    }
    console.log(a)
    return b;
}

console.log(getLargest([5.03, 7.09, 6.56,  9.09, 11.11], 3))
console.log(getLargest([5.03, 7.09, 6.56,  9.09, 11.11], 4))
console.log(getLargest([5.03, 7.09, 6.56,  9.09, 11.11], 1))
console.log(getLargest([5.03, 7.09, 6.56,  9.09, 11.11], 2))
```

for n loops, we are looking for the max and removing it from the original array and pushing it to new array. You can get n large elements.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the simplest method for finding the three largest numbers in a given array and the three indexes of the three largest numbers.

```html
<script>
      const orginalNumbers = [93, 17, 56, 91, 98, 33, 9, 38, 55, 78, 29, 81, 60];
      const orginalCopyNumbers = [];
      const orginalNumbersIndex = [];
      const threeLargestNumber = [];
      orginalCopyNumbers.push(...orginalNumbers);

      orginalNumbers.sort(function(a, b){
        return b - a 
      });

      for(var i=0;i<orginalCopyNumbers.length;i++){
        var index = orginalCopyNumbers.indexOf(orginalNumbers[i]);
        orginalNumbersIndex.push(index);
        threeLargestNumber.push(orginalNumbers[i]);
      }
      var threeLargestNumberIndex = orginalNumbersIndex.slice(0, 3);
      threeLargestNumberArray = threeLargestNumber.slice(0, 3);

      console.log(threeLargestNumberIndex);
      console.log(threeLargestNumberArray);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findMinAndMax(arr, largestBy=3) {
  arr = arr.sort((a,b) => a-b);

  let arr1 = arr.splice(0,largestBy);

  let highesMin = Math.max(...arr1); 
  console.log('highesMin', highesMin);

  let arr2 = arr.splice(arr.length - largestBy , largestBy);
  let lowestMax = Math.min(...arr2); 

  console.log('lowestMax', lowestMax);
```

}

let arr = [2,23,1,5,6,45,23,67];

findMinAndMax(arr, 2);

// OP
highesMin 2
lowestMax 45

Comment: What question does this answer? It does not `find 3 largest [elements and their] indexes in array?`. I expect run time grows in proportion to n log n where the code in the question is linear.

Answer (score 0):

First you can sort your array, and then the last three items are the answers. sort() and at() methods made it so easy:

```
scoreByPattern.sort(function(a, b) {return a-b});
console.log(scoreByPattern + "/******/" + scoreByPattern.at(-1) + 
    "/" + scoreByPattern.at(-2) + "/" + scoreByPattern.at(-3));
```